# Interrupting Skooma trade after previously clearing the cave

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have a big problem in Skyrim. I have a quest from Riften to interrupt the Skooma trade, but I already cleared the cave before accepting quest. Now when I go inside to interrupt trade, everything is already dead and I can't complete the quest.

How can I complete this quest if I have already killed the NPCs prior to accepting the quest?

Comment: Is this on PC??

Answer (score 0):

If you killed NPCs before completing the quest, you can try leaving the area and coming back at a different time to see if they respawned OR you can reload your previous save (before you killed them).

If you are playing on PC, you can spawn NPCs via the command console.  [A full list and tutorial on spawning NPCs is located on this Elder Scrolls Wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Console_Commands_(Skyrim)/Characters).